# Shapeless flatmap HList with Option yielding HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following

```
case class A(value:Int)
case class B(value:String)

val h:Option[A] :: A :: Option[B] :: Option[A] :: HNil = Some(A(1)) :: A(2) :: Some(B("two")) :: (None:Option[B]) :: HNil
```

How can I get the following ?

```
A(1) :: A(2) :: B("two") :: HNil
```

My attempt below

```
trait a extends Poly1 {
    implicit def any[T] = at[T](_ :: HNil)
}
object f extends a {            
    implicit def some[T] = at[Option[T]](t => if (t.isDefined) t.get :: HNil else HNil)         
}
```

works for map

```
h map f

> A(1) :: HNil :: A(2) :: HNil :: B(two) :: HNil :: HNil :: HNil
```

but fail for flatMap

```
h flatMap f

> could not find implicit value for parameter mapper: shapeless.ops.hlist.FlatMapper[f.type,shapeless.::[Option[A],shapeless.::[A,shapeless.::[Option[B],shapeless.::[Option[B],shapeless.HNil]]]]]
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. What's `f`? What does the argument to `flatMap` look like? Also as defined `h` is going to be statically typed as having `Some[A]`, etc. elements, which is pretty much never useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the only thing you can do is define separate cases for `Some` and for `None`:

```
trait a extends Poly1 {
  implicit def default[T] = at[T](_ :: HNil)
}
object f extends a {
  implicit def caseSome[T] = at[Some[T]](_.get :: HNil)
  implicit def caseNone = at[None.type](_ => HNil)
}
```

It also means you can't use generic `Option`s in the types, it *must* be known at compile time whether each element is `Some` or `None`:

```
scala> (Some(A(1)) :: A(2) :: Some(B("two")) :: None :: HNil) flatMap f
res1: shapeless.::[A,shapeless.::[A,shapeless.::[B,shapeless.HNil]]] = A(1) :: A(2) :: B(two) :: HNil
```

This distinction defines the type of the resulting expression: `Some(1) :: HNil flatMap f` will have type `::[Int, HNil]`, but `None :: HNil flatMap f` will have type just `HNil`.

This kind of type information can't be figured out at compile time from simple `Option`s: should `(x: Option[T]) :: HNil flatMap f` have type `::[T, HNil]` or `HNil`? We don't know until we actually run the program and see what the value of `x` is.

I'm not sure if there's some smart way to do it anyway and get an opaque `HList`, but at that point you'll abandon exact type information about each element and the length of the list and may as well cast it to a normal `List` (and maybe use `cast` from shapeless later if you know what exact type the final result will have)